# Understanding different ways of mocking or patching a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, monkeypatching

I am tyring to understand what are the differences between the following three ways of creating a mock function for usage in testing.

Suppose you have the following `application.py`(from [this link](https://www.freblogg.com/pytest-functions-mocking-1)):

```py
# application.py 
from time import sleep  
def is_windows():    
    # This sleep could be some complex operation instead
    sleep(5)    
    return True  
def get_operating_system():    
    return 'Windows' if is_windows() else 'Linux'
```

and the following `test_application.py`

```py
# test_application.py
from unittest.mock import patch

import application
from application import get_operating_system

# * Non-mocked test behaviour
# def test_get_operating_system():
#     assert get_operating_system() == 'Windows'

#  Mocked test behaviour
# In this example, I mock the slow function and return True always
# - 1) 'mocker' fixture provided by pytest-mock
def test_get_operating_system_1(mocker):
    mocker.patch('application.is_windows', return_value=True) 
    assert get_operating_system() == 'Windows'

# - 2) 'monkeypatch' fixture
def test_get_operating_system_2(monkeypatch):
    def mock_is_windows(*args, **kwargs):
        return True
    monkeypatch.setattr(application, 'is_windows', mock_is_windows)
    assert get_operating_system() == 'Windows'

# - 3) 'patch' from unittest.mock
@patch.object(application, 'is_windows', return_value=True)
def test_get_operating_system_3(mock_system):
    assert get_operating_system() == 'Windows'
```

These tests all pass, but seem to behave differently, although from the [pytest-mock](https://pytest-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/contents.html), and [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#module-unittest.mock) documentations I cannot fully understand those differences.

Therefore these are my "simple" questions:

- What are the differences between test 1, 2, 3?
- When is it more convenient to use each one of them?
- What other strategies can I use to patch tests?

Comment: I'm struggling with the same question, anyone wants to answer please?